# Custom Environment optional argument ignored

Tags: environments, enumerate, resume

I'm using an `enumerate` environment in my custom environment. Normally, a list may be resumed by adding the `resume` attribute after starting the list. However, the `resume` attribute is ignored in my custom environment. This leads to the behavior of starting a new list every time. My targeted custom environment contains more code, but I reduced it to the important part for simplicity.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newenvironment{questionlist}
{
    \begin{enumerate}[{resume}]} % should lead to a resuming list
    {\end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}

first part  

    \begin{questionlist}
        \item first
        \item second
    \end{questionlist}

second part % currently, produces a new list starting from 1 again and not from 3 

    \begin{questionlist}
        \item third
        \item fourth
    \end{questionlist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have changed your code

```
\newenvironment{questionlist}
{
    \begin{enumerate}[{resume}]} % should lead to a resuming list
    {\end{enumerate}
}
```

to

```
\newenvironment{questionlist}
    {
        \enumerate[resume]
    }
    {
    \endenumerate
    }
```

and it works.

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newenvironment{questionlist}
{
    \enumerate[resume]
}
{
\endenumerate
}
\begin{document}

first part  

    \begin{questionlist}
        \item first
        \item second
    \end{questionlist}

second part % currently, produces a new list starting from 3

    \begin{questionlist}
        \item third
        \item fourth
    \end{questionlist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative to Sebastianos answer, use `enumitem`s build in features to make new lists and then add `resume` as a property of that list

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{questionlist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[questionlist]{
  label=\arabic*.,
  resume
}
\begin{document}

first part  

\begin{questionlist}
\item first
\item second
\end{questionlist}

second part % currently, produces a new list starting from 1 again and not from 3 

\begin{questionlist}
\item third
\item fourth
\end{questionlist}

\end{document}
```